# How do I implement backbone into my hangman javascript game?

Tags: backbone.js

I had created a hangman javascript game using html/css and javascript. Now I'm a beginner programmer so my code looks like what they call spaghetti code. Now I'm starting to look into backbone.js because from what I've read it makes code have structure (Please let me know if I misunderstood the purpose of backbone). If you want to see my code it is here https://github.com/bboyjacks/hangman-javascript.git although it is unnecessary since you'll just see messy codes. I want to implement backbone into this game for the purposes of learning backbone by practice. The thing is I'm not sure how to get started.

How would I design my MVC for this game on backbone?

With that I mean. What would go inside my model? What would go inside my controller? and what would be in my views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your view should render your game interface from time to time.
The model supposed to be responsible for checking the game state.

For beginner tutorials see (beginner section):
http://backbonetutorials.com/

also, Google can help you a lot:
http://backbone-hangman.heroku.com/